# Call dynamic method

Tags: php

Let's suppose that I have a class with a method `getWorkDays()` that returns an Object. That object has other methods like `setMonday($val)`, `setTuesday($val)`..

What I'm trying to do is to call those methods dynamically:

```
$weekDays = array('sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday');

foreach($weekDays as $weekDayName){                
    call_user_func($obj->getWorkDays()->set{ucfirst($weekDayName)}, array(1));     
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can call your function with $obj->set{$weekDayName}(). Just, do a upper call on the first letter.

Comment: method names in php are case-insensitive, so no need to use ucfirst (or any other formatting function).

Answer (score 1):

here the code:

```
$weekDayName = ucfirst($weekDayName);
$obj->set{$weekDayName}();
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are on right track. you have syntax error in calling `set()` method. you have missed `()` in this method calling. it should be something like this:

```
call_user_func($obj->getWorkDays()->set{ucfirst($weekDayName)}(), array(1));
```

or you can split it out:

```
$objFirst = $obj->getWorkDays();
$params = $objFirst->set{ucfirst($weekDayName)}();

call_user_func($params,array(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$day = ucfirst($weekDayName);
$method = "set{$day}"; 
call_user_func($obj->getWorkDays()->$method, array(1));
```